# HttpContext.Current.Items is too fast to access item, but How?

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, asp.net-cache, asp.net-caching

I wrote simple test

1. add 100 items to [Collection]
2. read 1000000 times from [Collection] randomly

When

- [Collection]==HttpContext.Current.Items it takes 50 ms
- [Collection]==HttpRuntime.Cache it takes 430ms
- [Collection]==HashTable || [Collection]==Dictionaty 170ms

I guess the overhead of HttpRuntime.Cache is sync

I try to change initial capacity of HashTable/Dictionary? but with no success.

Does anyone know what is the reason of this turbo HttpContext.Current.Items?
May I create this kind of object to custom cache implementation(of course with sync imply).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason cache is sluggish is because it is [thread safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bx0tk8a.aspx) - as you guessed.

Underlying type for `HttpContext.Current.Items` is a plain `Hashtable`. Perhaps if you put a snippet of your code, I would be able to explain the difference with the 3rd item.

Comment: Yes your right! The reason of HashTable/Dictionary overhead is some .ToString() and boxing/unboxing calls. For pure HttpContext.Current.Items and HashTable. HT is little faster.